# 6in4 tunnel on Debian 9

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunnel

I have a VPS that has a /64 IPv6 address block assigned to it. I'm trying to deploy a 6in4 tunnel from my pfSense router at home and be able to access IPv6 addresses through that tunnel.

> I'm successful in bringing the gateway up, but I cannot ping any other IPs other than the /64 from my pfSense box. Ping from the VPS works though.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces config -

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 123.456.xxx.yyy
    netmask 24
    gateway 123.456.xxx.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address aaaa:bbbb:my:ipv6::1
    netmask 48
    gateway aaaa:bbbb::1

auto tunnel0
iface tunnel0 inet6 v4tunnel
    address aaaa:bbbb:my:ipv6::9
    netmask 64
    endpoint 66.abc.def.20
    up ip -6 route add aaaa:bbbb:my:ipv6::/64 via aaaa:bbbb:my:ipv6::10
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
    pre-up ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Here is the iptables rule for v4

```
iptables -I INPUT -p 41 -s 66.abc.def.20 -j ACCEPT
```

Here is the ip6tables rules for v6

```
ip6tables -I FORWARD -i tunnel0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I FORWARD -o tunnel0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have also added the following lines to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=2
```

The tunnel endpoint on my pfSense router is aaaa:bbbb:my:ipv6::10.

Comment: Your address edits make it impossible to understand the subnetting scheme you're using. Are you trying to duplicate the same prefix on both interfaces? Why is your eth0 configured as a /48 instead of /64? Is the /64 actually routed to you by the provider, or is it merely an on-link range?

Comment: @grawity - When I deployed the VM, eth0 inet6 config is generated with netmask 48 and I didn't disturb it. My understanding is that, if my tunnel endpoints are in the same subnet as the actual VM's IPv6 subnet, I'll be able to communicate with the BGP neighbor of the VM from my pfSense box using the tunnel. Also, the /64 assigned to the VPS is on-link I believe.

Comment: No, duplicating the same subnet in 2 or 3 places absolutely _doesn't_ help with routing... However, your main problem is the onlink assignment.

Comment: Any way I can use an on-link assignment to establish this tunnel? I'm trying to set this up on Vultr which offers BGP session and does only on-link assignments.

Comment: Hmm, aren't those rather contradictory? If you advertise your own prefix via BGP, then the peer will _always_ route it towards you, as that's the whole point of BGP. On the other hand, if you're using _Vultr's_ address space, then I don't understand how BGP is involved.

Comment: The plan is to establish a tunnel between Vultr and the pfSense box, run a Bird on Vultr VM that established eBGP with Vultr and iBGP with the pfSense machine. The pfSense machine will advertise my IPv6 space to Vultr VM which in turn forwards that to Vultr's ASN.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your connections look like this – subnet 1 is Vultr's global /48, and subnet 3 will be your own BGP-announced address space:

```
[Vultr router] ---subnet 1--- [Your VPS] ---subnet 2--- [pfSense] ---subnet 3--- <LAN>
```

So first of all, it *doesn't* make much sense to use the same /64 prefix on all three subnets – when you do that, you just give contradictory instructions to the router.

Not helping is the fact that this prefix isn't actually routed to your VPS; Vultr sees it as just an undividable chunk of the on-link /48. So when Vultr's router tries to reach `aaaa:bbbb:my:ipv6::10` (your pfSense), it doesn't know that the packets should be sent to your VPS – it thinks the address is on-link and tries to discover it using ND (ARP).

There are hacks that make it possible (such as ND/ARP proxying), but do you actually need that? No, because you have plenty of your own IP space.

So instead take a /64 from your BGP-advertised block (e.g. if you own `2001:db8:12::/48`, then `2001:db8:12:ffff::/64` would be a common choice) and configure *that* as the tunnel prefix.